# how to install Xscreensaver?

Tags: package-management, xscreensaver

i've been trying to install this all morning, but i get this error. i don't know hoow to solve it... Im on ubuntu 18.04

[image: unable to find package xscreensaver]

Comment: Due to your unusual color configuration your screenshot is hard to read. On this site it is recommended to copy and paste your terminal text to the question. Highlight the terminal text with with your mouse and use `Ctrl`+`C` to copy it to your clipboard. Then edit your question, position the cursor to where the text should be pasted and use `Ctrl`+`V` to paste the text from the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Universe repo enabled

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

and you have updated your package lists

`sudo apt-get update`

Then try installing screensaver.